# MvcScaffolding doesn't work with EF4.1-Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I recently installed the EF4.1-Update. When I made a new MVC3 Project and tried to add the MvcScaffolding using the PackageManagerConsole in VS2010 it wouldn't install it. Has anyone else 
seen this? I removed the EF4.1-Update from my machine and MvcScaffolding installs correctly.

thanks,
Bill44077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It does work. And it works beautifully**

But I had some issues getting it all setup.

What error(s) did you get exactly I had a number of issues, but solved them one by one.

Did you get this sort of thing in PMC when VS started up?

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2943) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
```

If so either update .net Refelector (now costs), or go Tools > Add-In Manager and disable the .NEt Reflector add in ! THEN RESTART VS

Or if you try to scaffold something, do you get e.g.

```
Invoke-Scaffolder : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name -ModelType"
```

?

Do you get errors when you try to add a controller to your MVC 3 project?

Are you running on Windows (pre 7) + without powershell 2.0 installed?

Basically don't worry it does work, I think the order or installations matters, just work through it bit by bit, its worth it.

Comment: Ben,Yes - that above error was the exact one that I was getting when PMC started up. I didn't not have Reflector as an Add-In but there were 2 others so I removed them to see if it would solve my issue. It did but then I also had to update NuGet to V1.4. Thanks Much!!

Comment: So you got it working? If so great ! Its brought a lot of joy to me ! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to clean out the packages folder in your solution and reinstall the MvcScaffolding. Once you do this everything should sync back up.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Hi Chris - thanks for the suggestion. Since I installed the EF Update and then created a new project, that project would be creating a new packages folder. Are you suggesting removing everything from the packages folder and then re-add them (jQuery, EF, Modernizr, etc)? Is that what you mean by "Clean out"? Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, I ran into a similar problem right after MvcScaffolding was placed into the MVC3 update which was pushed out a few months ago. It seems that deleting these items from the project and using Nuget to reinstall them solves theh dependency problems and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reinstalling the update after the scaffolding is installed?  I already had the scaffolding installed when I installed Update 1, so i did not see a problem.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion. I will try that, but I am concerned about after the EF Update is installed that I won't be able to make a new MVC3 project and add MvcScaffolding to it. That wouldn't be good. Have you tried creating a new MVC3 project and adding MvcScaffolding since your install of EF-Update? Thanks!!

Comment: Don't worry, you can expect some issues, but it does work in the end.

Comment: Hi Ben,Thanks! Sorry, I was off on a week long tangent last week. I'll try this again today. I was getting the error when I was trying to use PM to install MvcScaffolding from VS2010. I'll respond back here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when the scaffolding.config file was either not present, or not filled with the Default Scaffolders -- make sure its populated with the default entries for views, controllers, etc. I think there is 9 by default in version 1.0.9.

Old post I know but this is still relevant in project templates and autogenerated projects -- the scaffolding.config needs to have its defaults.